change newline with space on certain condition with sed
I have the following text in a file:
#1713251479
sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495
nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186
sh lowbat.sh

and I want to put the Unix timestamp inline with the command like this:
#1713251479 sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495 nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186 sh lowbat.sh

I tried the following sed command:
sed -zE '/^#/ s/\n/ /g' file.txt
sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;/^#/ s/\n/ /g' file.txt

The replace operation is applied but the condition is ignored, what am I missing here?

In both your attempts, you read the whole file into the editing buffer and then replace all newlines with a space (the text will start with a #, so the substitution triggers in both cases and is carried out on the whole buffer). This will not generate the correct output as it would collect all text onto a single output line.
Using paste instead to create two tab-delimited columns.  The utility will match one line of input with each - in its arguments:
$ paste - - <file
#1713251479     sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495     nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186     sh lowbat.sh

Would you want to use a space in place of a tab, use paste with -d ' ':
$ paste -d ' ' - - <file
#1713251479 sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495 nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186 sh lowbat.sh

With sed, append the next line to the current buffer and replace the newline character that sed uses to delimit the two with a space:
$ sed 'N; y/\n/ /' file
#1713251479 sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495 nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186 sh lowbat.sh

Would you want to make the joining of the lines conditional on the # character at the start of a line:
$ sed '/^#/ { N; y/\n/ /; }' file
#1713251479 sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495 nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186 sh lowbat.sh

With ed, you can apply a substitution to add a space at the end of each line that starts with a #, then join the next line onto the end of it with the j command:
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^#/ s/$/ /\' j ,p Q | ed -s file
#1713251479 sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495 nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186 sh lowbat.sh

The following works by joining each line that doesn't start with a # to the previous line, after adding a space at the start.  This would join all lines to the most recent line starting with # (the example has been altered to show one instance of this).
$ cat file
#1713251479
sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495
nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186
sh lowbat.sh
sh hibat.sh
$ printf '%s\n' 'v/^#/ s/^/ /\' '-,.j' ,p Q | ed -s file
#1713251479 sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495 nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186 sh lowbat.sh sh hibat.sh


Perl is a great tool for this sort of thing:
$ perl -pe 's/\n/ / if /^#/' file
#1713251479 sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495 nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186 sh lowbat.sh

The -p tells perl to print each input line after applying the script given by -e. Here, the script is simply the substitution operator which you are already familiar with from sed, and we only apply the substitution if the current line starts with a #.
Alternatively, you can slurp the whole file into memory and use more fancy regex magic (lookahead) to replace all \n characters that are followed by a non-# character:
$ perl -0 -pe 's/\n(?=[^#])/ /g; ' file
#1713251479 sh lowbat.sh
#1713251495 nvim lowbat.sh
#1713252186 sh lowbat.sh

